# Posting OneToMany database records in thymeleaf templates

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I've got 2 classes - Contact and Phone, class Contact has  a Set of Phones .
Here's mine controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ContactFormController {

@Autowired
ContactRepository contactRepo;

@Autowired
PhoneRepository phoneRepo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAll(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contacts", contactRepo.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("phones",  phoneRepo.findAll());
    return "dataresult";
}
```

I want to display records of my database through thymeleaf template, here's my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Dane</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>Dane</h3>
<p th:each="contact : ${contacts}">
    <h4>ID:</h4>
    <div th:text="${contact.id}"></div>
    <h4>Name:</h4>
    <div th:text="${contact.firstName}"></div>
    <li th:each="item : ${contact.phones}" th:text="${item}">Item description   here...</li>
    <div>---------</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've got as result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgeqK.png
Phone class - http://pastebin.com/L6Sqsp9q
Contact class has a
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "contactId")
    private Set phones;

How can i make my controller to display Contact id, name AND Set of phone numbers ?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i dont know how to do this, I'm total noob on thymeleaf and html. Although i think i have to somehow acces number field on Phone class but i dont know how

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I failed to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is printing the `Phone` itself which explains your output. What you need to do is access the `number` field of the `item`. For example,

```
th:each="item : ${contact.phones}" th:text="${item.number}"
```

or,

```
th:each="item : ${contact.phones}" th:text="${item.getNumber()}"
```

Comment: thank you very much! it's working. I think I'll have one more issue, can I ask you for help one more time in a while ? :)

Comment: @newbie101, no problem, glad to help. You may show your appreciation by accepting it as the answer and giving it an upvote :)

Comment: You can @ me if you like. I will be in class for most of the remainder of the day but will check back later this evening @newbie101.

Comment: alright. this is code is working and it's adding a new record to the base but only with name. http://pastebin.com/py11UTWm
I dont know how to make form for typing in number though.
here's html  - http://pastebin.com/qQxKdZqQ

Comment: @newbie101, you need another input (`<input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" />`) but for the number(s). If you have a list of numbers that aren't differentiated by "home", "work", or similar, you'd need to have a dynamic way to add another upon request.

Comment: I dont need it dynamic by now, I just want to add 1 phone number. The problem is that i dont know how to acces this field, becouse contact class has a Set of Phones, and Phone class has a number field...

I've figured something like this, and this is adding contact to the database and EMPTY phone, with only ID. http://pastebin.com/vuZXMhA9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102539/discussion-between-newbie101-and-chieftwopencils).